# Set app start page to a specific URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

My app currently starts at the following URL

```
www.myapp.com/dashboard/overview
```

The controller and action method can be changed from with in the config file. I have several partial views which are rendered using javascript that get displayed into the  `overview.cshtml` file, which acts as template. I was wondering if it would be possible to set the starting URL to the following when a user first lands on the app.

```
www.myapp.com/dashboard/overview?v=home
```

the `v=home`is how we are currently routing to that specific partial view from with in other areas of the application when the URL is different from what I have above. I'm looking for the best way to implement this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Razor, I'd put that at the beginning of the view like this :

```
If(Request["v"] == null)
       return RedirectToAction("overview", new { v = "home"});
```

Comment: I get an error, it doesn't look like the 'RedirectToAction' method is available to me in the view with razor.

Comment: Hum, sorry, Haven't user Razor sntax that much. Actually, you should try to put the code I gave you int the Controller of you page in the method called by the View. Just replace " Request.Parameters" by " HTTPContext.Request.Parameters["v"] " . That should do the trick !

Comment: so this does in fact work for setting the staring page. Now the only issue is when I click on a menu item that uses that same controller it just ends upp forcing this partial view again.

Comment: Ok, you can set a flag that tell you if you have have already been redirected. Set it to true when you redirect for the first time. When it is true don't redirect anymore.

Comment: Actually what I did was make a new action result for it. And with in that result did the following RedirectToAction("Overview", "Dashboard," , new {v = "home"}); and set that action method to a config item. If you want to edit one of your answers I will mark it as the answer, since you helped out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the Page load of your Home page just do like this :

```
If(Request.Parameters["v"] == null)
     Response.Redirect("www.myapp.com/dashboard/overview?v=home")
```

This will redirect you towards the same page with the param if "v" is not set while calling the page.

Comment: Would I apply this to the controller handling the 'overview' render action or in the view itself using razor?